# Spring MVC: Blob and float are not read in json format

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having a problem viewing the product list in json; in particular the problem is in displaying image which is blob type and the price (float type).

As you can see below, image and price are not read as Json format.
Do you need to make any changes in the visualization method?

```html
"Prodcode": "IPH12",
        "Name": "iPhone12 PRO",
        "Image": [B@73b2a9cc,
            "Price": 1123.99
        },
        {
            "Prodcode": "MCC23",
            "Name": "Macchina Fotografica Nikon",
            "Image": [B@3cccd41a,
                "Price": 220.99
            }
```

Dao:

```js
public List<Map<String, Object>> readViewListProductJson() {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM product");
        }
```

Controller:

```js
@RequestMapping(value  = {"/products-list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
        public String ViewListProduct() {
            return JSONArray.toJSONString(productDao.readViewListProductJson());
        }
```

Comment: Are you expecting with " "

Comment: JSON Shaw based on the data type

Comment: If it boolea it will Shaw as true or false, if any number or float it will as it is.

Comment: so what should I do? can you explain yourself better kindly?